# TikZ - Figure depicting the equilibrium structure of a game (with text within two axes)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-pic

I am trying to produce the following figure depicting the equilibrium/equilibria structure of a game (game theory) with some text within two axes (X and C, separating them by dashed lines connected to two points at axis X) using Tikz:

[image: equilibrium structure]

All I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=2,
     > = Stealth,
dot/.style = {circle, draw=black, solid, 
          fill=#1, % default blue!50
          minimum size=3pt, inner sep=0pt,
          node contents={}},
dot/.default = blue!50,
domain=0:5, samples=100,
                    ]
% axis
\draw[->] (-0.6,0) -- (10,0.0) node [below left] {$X$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,3.5) node [below left] {$C$};
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think of at least two different ways: the first is to write the text on 3 columns in the usual way with LaTeX and then to make the axes and dashed lines on top.
The second is to do everything with TikZ using `matrix` to write the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
                > = Straight Barb,
    node distance = 0mm,
box/.style = {minimum height=#1, text width=32mm, align=left, % center?
              inner sep=2mm, outer sep =0pt, anchor=south west}
                    ]
\node (n1) [box=60mm] {TEXT, TEX, TEXT, TEXT, TEXT, TEXT}; 
\node (n2) [box=30mm, 
            above right=of n1.south east] {TEXT, TEX, TEXT, TEXT, TEXT, TEXT};
\node (n3) [box=30mm,
            above=of n2] {TEXT, TEXT, EXT, TEXT, TEXT, TEXT};
\node (n4) [box=60mm,
            above right=of n2.south east] {TEXT, TEX, TEXT, TEXT, TEXT, TEXT};
% borders
\draw[dashed]   (n1.north east) -- (n1.south east) node[below] {$\bar{R} - L_p$}
                (n4.north west) -- (n4.south west) node[below] {$\bar{R}$}
                (n2.north west) -- (n2.north east);
% axis
\draw[->] (-0.4,0) -- (10,0) node [below left] {$X$};
\draw[->] (0,-0.4) -- node[left] {$\dfrac{a}{b}$} 
                      ( 0,7) node [below left] {$C$};
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is added now. see corrected answer. Correct text in axis labels I left to you.